# C# 4.0 async task results

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I have a program on .net 4.5 but I have to downgrade to .net 4.0.
My code is following:

```
public static async Task<string> ServerReq(string key, string url, string[] post=null)
{
   ...
   return await response;
}
private void newMethod()
{
   var task = Task.Run(async () => await ServerReq(readText, "/ssh/index.php/api/auth"));
   task.Wait();
   if (task.IsCompleted)
   {
      string taskResults = task.Result;
   }
}
```

I have installed Microsoft BLC components to get async/await work. But there is no task.run method in C#4. I've tried to replace it to Task.Factory.StartNew and there are no errors, but I can't get any results. What's wrong? How to port this code to 4.0? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you attempted that doesn't work on 4.0?  You are only showing us your old code that does work on 4.5.

Comment: I've tried this way: var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await ServerReq(readText, "/ssh/index.php/api/auth")); but there is some problem with converting <string> to string...

Comment: What I meant was, that you should edit your original post to include the 4.0 version of your code, and then be clear about what errors or results you are getting.  For instance, if you are still attempting to use the `async` keyword, then it won't even compile, right?

Comment: It does compile because I do use Microsoft BLC components from NuGet which implement async/await in .net 4.0.

Comment: You are right. Sorry about that. :)

Comment: The only thing I changed was this string, but I cannot get any result. But it seems task starts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the BLC the `Run` method is on the `TaskEx` class instead of `Task`

```
var task = TaskEx.Run(() => ServerReq(readText, "/ssh/index.php/api/auth"));
string taskResults = task.Result;
```

Comment: So simple.. Thank you so much, It works now! Just wonder how could I get results with Task.Factory.StartNew...

Comment: You don't even need the await, the code should be  `TaskEx.Run(() => ServerReq(readText, "/ssh/index.php/api/auth")` it has a overload that takes `Func<Task>`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's right, I simplified my code

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Of course, you don't even need *that*.  The method can just be `return ServerReq(readText, "/ssh/index.php/api/auth")`.  There's no need to wrap the already asynchronous operation in a call to `Run`.

Comment: @Servy It could be that the first part of the asynchronous operation contains some large amount of synchronous work (I have run in to this where EntityFrameworks model checks are done synchronously on your first query so even though you do a `SaveChangesAsync()` you still might want it on a background thread for that first call) , but I do agree, it is odd that the OP is performing a Task.Run on a already asynchronous operation.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `ServerReq` is his own method, not a library method, so if there's anything like that going on I'd expect it to be the responsibility of *that* method to make the operation asynchronous, given that it exposes an asynchronous API.